# match multiline pattern non-greedy with sed?

Tags: regex, sed, multiline

infile:

```
[start] cmd1
afadfadf
dafdf
[ok] cmd1
[-] cmd2
[-] cmd3
[start] cmd4
dfdafadf
d
afasdf

daf
[stop] cmd4
[-] cmd5
[-] cmd6
[start] cmd1
adfadd
dafa
dfdd33r55ae
[ok] cmd1
[-] cmd7
[start] cmd8
error...

[stop] cmd8
[-] cmd9
[start] cmd10
exit xx

[stop] cmd10
[-] cmd
[start] cmd1
[ok] cmd1
```

I would like to print all blocks like: [start] ... [stop] cmd...

result should be:

```
[start] cmd4
dfdafadf
d
afasdf

daf
[stop] cmd4
[start] cmd8
error...

[stop] cmd8
[start] cmd10
exit xx

[stop] cmd10
```

how can I do this with sed?

`sed -n '/\[start\]/I,/\[stop\]/I p'` will not work, because the range operator would not stop until it find the next [stop].

EDIT:
after using @jaybee sed script I found it still have some **issue**, ***when there is more [stop] line than start line***, for example:

infile2

```
[start] cmd1
afadfadf
dafdf
[ok] cmd1
[-] cmd2
[-] cmd3
[start] cmd4
dfdafadf
d
afasdf

daf
[stop] cmd4
[-] cmd5
[-] cmd6
[start] cmd1
adfadd
dafa
dfdd33r55ae
[ok] cmd1
[-] cmd7
[start] cmd8
error...

[stop] cmd8
[-] cmd9
[stop] sum
[stop] cmd1
[stop] cmd2
[start] cmd10
exit xx

[stop] cmd10
[-] cmd
[start] cmd1
[ok] cmd1
```

It will still output the extra [stop] lines, like this:

```
[start] cmd4
dfdafadf
d
afasdf

daf
[stop] cmd4
[start] cmd8
error...

[stop] cmd8
[stop] cmd8
[-] cmd9
[stop] sum
[stop] sum
[stop] cmd1
[stop] cmd2
[stop] cmd2
[start] cmd10
exit xx

[stop] cmd10
```

so I decide to modify the sedsrc to fix this:

```
#n
/^\[start\]/I {h;d}
#if match [start] create a new hold buffer then delete the pattern space
/^\[stop\]/I {
#if match [stop] do this
H;x
#append line into hold buffer and then swap the hold buffer to pattern space
/^\[start\]/I{p;d}
#if the buffer contain [start], then it is a complete [start]...[stop] block, print the block,start over with next line
d
#if does not contain [start],start over with next line
}
/^\[.+\]/ {
#if it is other control word, do this
h;d
# clear and put current line to hold buffer, start over with next line
}

H
#append non-control line into hold buffer
```

now it works OK, welcome for future discussion about how to make the script more concise.

Comment: So what do you want? What would the expected output be in your example?

Comment: @hek2mgl, please do not change my `infile`!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I suggest you use the hold buffer, flushing it whenever you see a fresh `[start]` and printing it whenever you see `[stop]`. This gives the following script:

```
#n
/^\[start\]/I {
    h;n
}
/^\[stop\]/I {
    H;x;p;n
}
H
```

You put this in e.g. `sedscr` and then run it to get the following result:

```
$ sed -f sedscr infile
[start] cmd4
dfdafadf
d
afasdf

daf
[stop] cmd4
[start] cmd1
adfadd
dafa
dfdd33r55ae
[stop] cmd1
[start] cmd8
error...

[stop] cmd8
[start] cmd10
exit xx

[stop] cmd10
```

#### Explanation

Seeing `[start]` at the beginning of the line (with the `I` flag as it seems you want to go case-insensitive), put that line into the hold space, erasing its previous content (`h`) and then feed in the next line (`n`).

When one sees `[stop]`, append that line to the hold space (`H`), then swap pattern space and hold space (`x`) to print the pattern space (`p`), and then feed in the next line (`n`).

And on all other lines, simply append the line to the current hold space (`H`).

By the way, the `#n` at the beginning of my script is the equivalent of `-n` on the commandline: requesting **sed** not to output the pattern space to the output stream unless asked by a `p` command.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most neat way to do it. The explanation is very helpful also.

Comment: there is some issue, when the file contain more [stop] line than [start] line. See EDIT.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk` that should work:

```
awk '/^\[start\]/ {i=1;delete a}  {a[i++]=$0} /^\[stop\]/ {for (j=1;j<i;j++) print a[j]}' file
[start] cmd4
dfdafadf
d
afasdf

daf
[stop] cmd4
[start] cmd1
adfadd
dafa
dfdd33r55ae
[stop] cmd1
[start] cmd8
error...

[stop] cmd8
[start] cmd10
exit xx

[stop] cmd10
```

It only print from `start` if it has an `end`
Every time it sees a `start` it resets an array and start storing data to it.
If a `stop` is found, print out the array.

Comment: It's greedy, exactly what the OP doesn't want: it prints everything from any unbalanced `[start]...[start]...[stop]` chunk, for instance.

Comment: @jaybee Updated my post.  It would have helped a lot if OP did give an output example.  This is also why I normally always add the output from my commands to see if its this OP wants.

Comment: sure, you're right. +1 for your solution, implementing **sed**'s hold space with an array :) But you should rather have `/^\[start\]/` as pattern, instead of just /start/. And apparently the (now silent) OP wants it case-insensitive...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/^\[start\|stop\]/I{:b;$!{n;/^\[/ba;bb}};d' file
```

If the line begins `[start]` or `[stop]` (upper or lowercase), print it and any subsequent lines that don't begin `[`. If the next line begins with a `[` loop back to the beginning and check again, otherwise delete it.

EDIT:

An alternate answer might be:

```
sed '/^\[start\]/I{h;d};H;/^\[stop\]/I{x;p;x};d' file
```

EDIT:

In light of the question being amended:

```
sed '/^\[start\]/I{:a;x;/^\(.*\[stop\][^\n]*\).*/Is//\1/p;x;h;d};H;$ba;d' file
```

Comment: @jaybee perhaps but have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, of course, and for instance it outputs the first three lines of the example given by the OP, which is -- I think -- not desired.

Comment: Your second answer (EDIT section) is right, but IMHO is not very different from my solution below (`h;d` instead of `h;n`, etc).